# Undefined method `authenticate' in Rails 4 Mongoid with has_secure_password

Tags: authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have seen others questions about Mongoid and has_secure_password but my case is different, on creation the "ActiveModel::SecurePassword" do the job well, the password_digest is created without problems. But when I try to authenticate I get the error: "**undefined method `authenticate' for Mongoid::Criteria:0x007fe2b0d99488**" pointing to the line "**@room.authenticate(params[:password])**" of my checkpoints_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    @room = Room.where(url: params[:room_url])
    if @room && @room.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[@room.id.to_s.to_sym] = true
      redirect_to "/chat/" + @room.url
    else
      redirect_to "/checkpoint/" + @room.url, alert: "This room may not exists or your password is incorrect."
    end
  end
```

In my model room.rb everything seems fine:

```
class Room
  include Mongoid::Document
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
  embeds_one :guest
  embeds_many :messages

  has_secure_password
  field :password_digest
  field :owner_name
  field :url

end
```

I am using: Rails 4.0.0 and Mongoid 4.0.0.beta1.

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
 @room = Room.where(url: params[:room_url])
```

with this line

```
 @room = Room.where(url: params[:room_url]).first
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a similar situation. What worked for me was moving the has_secure_password after the field password_digest.

```html
class Room
  include Mongoid::Document
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
  embeds_one :guest
  embeds_many :messages

  field :password_digest
  has_secure_password
  field :owner_name
  field :url

end
```